# Serialize a Dictionary<string,object> containing List<string> as value

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm using a [`SerializableDictionary`](http://www.dacris.com/blog/2010/07/31/c-serializable-dictionary-a-working-example/) class from a blog and I'm also using some complex types to serialize. Unfortunately I receive an error and don't know how to solve this.

One thing to note is that I'm using Mono, since I'm using Unity3D. I don't know if this makes this issue different and I've not yet tested if .net also returns this error.

This is the upper part of the stacktrace:

> InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   is not primitive.
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive
>   (System.String name, System.String ns, System.Object o, Boolean
>   xsiType)

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            string result = f.Serialize();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        private SerializableDictionary<string, object> dict;

        public Foo()
        {
            dict = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();
            dict.Add("list", new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" });
        }

        public string Serialize()
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(dict.GetType(), new Type[] {typeof(List<string>)});
            StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
            x.Serialize(w, dict);
            return w.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** :
I've created a test program in .NET and it tells me that *{"The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String,...]] may not be used in this context."}*.

I've updated the sample code above.

Answer (score 1):

First check if error will persist after you specify value type in SerializableDictionary.

also specifying inner types may help:

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(myobjects.GetType(), new[] { typeof(List<string>) } );
```

PS: You may also look into Json.Net ;)

**Update 1:**

If you specify value type for SerializableDictionary code sample code will work:

```
...
private SerializableDictionary<string, List<string>> dict;

public Foo()
{
    dict = new SerializableDictionary<string, List<string>>();
    dict.Add("list", new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" });
}
```

**Update 2:**

"Bug" is in SerializableDictionary class in ValueSerializer:

```
protected XmlSerializer ValueSerializer
{
    get
    {
        if (valueSerializer == null)
        {
            valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TVal));
        }
        return valueSerializer;
    }
}
```

If you set object as TVal, XmlSerializer won't be able to serialize List.

**Update 3:**

If you don't know value type you can try specifying all possible complex types in extra types:

```
protected XmlSerializer ValueSerializer
{
    get
    {
        if (valueSerializer == null)
        {
            valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TVal), 
                new[]
                    {
                        typeof(List<string>), 
                        typeof(List<int>)
                    });
        }
        return valueSerializer;
    }
}
```

Or use some dynamic framework like Json.NET:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("list", new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" });

var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

Console.WriteLine(str);

var dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
```

Comment: Adding typeof(List<string>) did not help unfortunately.

Comment: I'm afraid that we can't help you without sample of inner class that generates error.

Comment: I've updated my question with new sample code that returns the error.

Comment: I've seen the `ValueSerializer` and it seems that I can fix this by making a new `XmlSerializer` for each value, but during `Deserialize()` it seems almost impossible to find the type for the new XmlSerializer for each value I want to read from the dictionary.

Comment: So you have values of many types stored in SerializableDictionary<string, object>?

Comment: yes I do. It is a mapping of a special object in unity that doesn't allow [XmlRoot] and such, so I used reflection to get all properties and put them in a dictionary.

Comment: Try specifying all possible types in "extraTypes" like in update 3.

Comment: Specifying extra types gives me the error: *{"<ArrayOfString xmlns=''> was not expected."}*. I think I'll just create my own serializer.